# Beilinson's height pairing vs. Néron–Tate

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, heights, reference-request

In the literature there are several different definitions of what is often referred to as Beilinson's height pairing (see for example section 4.3.8 of Gillet and Soulé's paper [Arithmetic intersection theory](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1990__72__93_0/), and this [note](http://hodge.mathematik.uni-mainz.de/%7Estefan/papers/cime.pdf) of Müller-Stach). The height pairing is supposed to generalize the [Neron-Tate height pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9ron%E2%80%93Tate_height). Is there a precise statement in the literature where Beilinson's height pairing for an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ is compared to the Néron–Tate pairing?

Answer (score 2):

[Beilinson's original paper on Height pairings](https://doi.org/10.1090/conm/067/902590) does indicate how his height pairing generalises that of Néron–Tate: see page 10 (also, Müller-Stach and Kunneman's works expand on Remark 4.0.8 on page 14).
Also, [Scholl's paper](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eajs1005/preprints/height-all.pdf) provides a very nice interpretation (via Ext in mixed motives).